# помогите уменьшить код на си

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

> Написать логическое выражение для определения стоимости переговоров, если стоимость с 22 часов до 8 часов на 20% ниже, а в субботу и воскресенье дополнительно предоставляется скидка 10% (в сумме 30%). Использовать данные – t (время начала разговора от 0 до 23 часов), dt (продолжительность разговора в минутах), s (стоимость минуты разговора), d (день недели от 1 до 7).
> Примечание. Продолжительность разговора может быть сколь угодно большой. Допустим, разговор начался в пятницу в 15:00, а закончился в субботу в 23:00. Тогда во время разговора скидка менялась несколько раз: день буднего дня – нет скидки, ночь буднего – скидка 20%, ночь выходного – скидка 30%, потом день выходного – скидка 10%, потом ночь выходного – скидка 30%. Программа должна это учитывать.

Написала такой код, он работает, но как его уменьшить?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)  
{ 
int s,dt,t,d; 
float sum; 
printf("введите время начала разговора от 0 до 23 часов \n");  
  scanf("%d", &t); 
printf("введите продолжительность разговора в минутах \n");  
  scanf("%d", &dt); 
printf("стоимость минуты разговора \n");  
  scanf("%d", &s); 
printf("день недели от 1 до 7 \n"); 
  scanf("%d", &d); 
sum=0; 
while (dt!=0) 
  { 
  if (((t>=9) && (t<22)) && (d<6))  
  { 
    if (dt>60) 
    { 
       sum=sum+(60*s); 
       dt=dt-60; 
       } 
    else if (dt<=60)  
      { 
      sum=sum+(s*dt); 
      dt=0; 
      }  
  if (t!=23) ++t; 
  else  
    { 
    d=d+1; 
    t=0; 
    } 
  } 
  if (((t>=22) || (t<9)) && (d<6))  
    { 
     if (dt>60) 
      { 
       sum=sum+(60*s*0.8); 
       dt=dt-60; 
       } 
     else if (dt<=60)  
       { 
       sum=sum+(s*dt*0.8); 
       dt=0; 
       }  
  if (t!=23) ++t; 
  else {d=d+1; 
    t=0; 
    } 
  } 
  if (((t>=22) || (t<9)) && (d>5))  
   { 
   if (dt>60) 
      { 
       sum=sum+(60*s*0.7); 
       dt=dt-60; 
        } 
   else if (dt<=60)  
     { 
      sum=sum+(s*dt*0.7); 
      dt=0; 
      }  
  if (t!=23) ++t; 
  else  
    { 
     d=d+1; 
     t=0; 
     } 
    } 
  if (((t>=9) && (t<22)) && (d>5))  
     { 
if (dt>60) 
{ 
sum=sum+(60*s*0.9); 
dt=dt-60; 
} 
else if (dt<=60)  
{ 
sum=sum+(s*dt*0.9); 
dt=0; 
}  
if (t!=23) ++t;
else {d=d+1; 
t=0; 
} 
} 
} 
printf("sum= %f \n",sum); 
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

хм, тут 2 пути.. или функции делать или переменную добавить
чтоб уйти от повторений участка кода...
а переменную назовем, например, ДельтаСуммы `DS` или прирост...

можно еще контролировать правильность ввода переменных, но такой задачи не было

вот Вам для примера код, проверяйте на разных исходных данных

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)  
{ 
int s,dt,t,d; 
float sum,ds; 
printf("Введите время начала разговора от 0 до 23 часов \n");  
  scanf("%d", &t); 
printf("Введите продолжительность разговора в минутах \n");  
  scanf("%d", &dt); 
printf("Введите стоимость минуты разговора \n");  
  scanf("%d", &s); 
printf("Введите день недели от 1 до 7 \n"); 
  scanf("%d", &d); 
sum=0;

for(;dt > 0;dt -= 60)
{ 
    ds = 1;                         // день будни, полный тариф
    if ((t >= 22) || (t < 8))
            ds -= 0.2;              // ночная скидка 20% 
    if ( d > 5 ) 
            ds -= 0.1;              // скидка выходного дня 10% 

    if (dt > 60) 
    {   
        ds *= 60 * s;               //Дельта суммы = коэф. * полный час * стоимость
        if ( ++t == 24 )            //Переход на сл. сутки
        {   
            t = 0;
            if (++d == 8) 
                d = 1;              //Переход на сл. неделю 
        }
    }
    else 
        ds *= dt * s;               //Дельта суммы = коэф. * остаток часа * стоимость 
         
    sum += ds;
}

printf("Стоимость разговора: %.2f \n",sum); 
return 0; 
}
```

Пример тут: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/RrN35A)